How can I stop all check boxes being checked when I uncheck a single check box?
I am trying to implement a function which will uncheck other checkboxes when a new one is clicked. I am doing this instead of using radio because I want the possibility to uncheck by clicking on the subject.


function uncheck(obj) {
  var ch = document.getElementsByName('ch');
  for (var i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    if (ch[i].id != obj.id) {
      ch[i].checked = !obj.checked;
      break;
    }
  }
}
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 1" onclick="uncheck(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 2" onclick="uncheck(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 3" onclick="uncheck(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 4" onclick="uncheck(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 5" onclick="uncheck(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 6" onclick="uncheck(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 7" onclick="uncheck(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 8" onclick="uncheck(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 9" onclick="uncheck(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 10" onclick="uncheck(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 11" onclick="uncheck(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 12" onclick="uncheck(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 13" onclick="uncheck(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 14" onclick="uncheck(this)">



However, as the function works now, for some reason, if I check chapter 4, and then check chapter 1, it won't uncheck chapter 4. And when I uncheck chapter 1, for some reason it checks chapter 2, and if I uncheck chapter 2, it checks chapter 1.

Please, use let/const instead of var unless you have good reason. For for loops, avoid var unless you really know what you're doing.

Also note that @DarrylNoakes has (correctly) changed your [tag:java] tag to a [tag:javascript] tag. Please understand that these are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help.

Um, why the break? That's obviously going to stop the loop on the first element that isn't the clicked one

Also, this code applies to any click, whether the checkbox was checked or unchecked by the click. Unchecking a checkbox will run the function too, checking every other checkbox (if it weren't for the break bug`). You should check the current state.

The "best" algorithm for this is to check the current state, clear everything, and set new state. It's very simple: if this is now checked, uncheck all and check this. That's all.

@Ryochi ... If you want to be able to uncheck a radio-control from a radio-group you should implement it exactly that way. Why? Because with radio-controls and radio-groups you already  get all the expected/desired behavior for free (except the unchecking of all of a radio-group's radio-controls; Second, implementing the behavior of a radio-group based on checkbox-controls is more complex than enabling the uncheck-behavior of a radio-group and third, a user expects a certain behavior from checkboxes; a radio-control like switching is the last what the user does expect.

@Ryochi ... Regarding all the provided answers / solutions, are there any questions left?

You have a break statement in the body of the if: this will stop the loop on the first element that isn't the clicked one.
Removing that reveals another issue: all the checkboxes will be set when one is clicked, to the inverse of the clicked one's state. Checking one unchecks all the others, but unchecking one checks all the others. This is because they are set to the inverse of the clicked boxes state, not to unchecked.
A not so consequential issue is using var; I will use let/const. Also, for the sake of clarity, I am going to make variable and function names more clear. And reduce the number of boxes.
Fixing those yields us this:


function handleClick(current) {
  const boxes = document.getElementsByName('ch');
  for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    if (boxes[i].id != current.id) {
      boxes[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
}
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 1" onclick="handleClick(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 2" onclick="handleClick(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 3" onclick="handleClick(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 4" onclick="handleClick(this)">



That works.
Simplify using iterators
But it can be improved using iterators! The getElementsByName method returns a NodeList, which is iterable; because of this, we can use a for...of loop.


function handleClick(current) {
  const boxes = document.getElementsByName('ch');
  for (box of boxes) {
    if (box.id != current.id) {
      box.checked = false;
    }
  }
}
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 1" onclick="handleClick(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 2" onclick="handleClick(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 3" onclick="handleClick(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 4" onclick="handleClick(this)">



Tada! Much simpler and clearer.
Alternative algorithm
This is the alternative algorithm I suggested: save the state of the clicked box, clear everything, and then set the state of the clicked box.


function handleClick(current) {
  const boxes = document.getElementsByName('ch');

  const wasChecked = current.checked;
  for (box of boxes) {
    box.checked = false;
  }
  current.checked = wasChecked;
}
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 1" onclick="handleClick(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 2" onclick="handleClick(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 3" onclick="handleClick(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 4" onclick="handleClick(this)">



That satisfies me as to the core algorithm code.
Some other improvements
Some other improvements...
Move the definition of boxes out of the handler, so it isn't recalculated on every click:
const boxes = document.getElementsByName('ch');

// ...

function handleClick(current) {

Use addEventListener instead of event attributes (assuming the HTML is static):
boxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener("click", handleClick))

Use the proper change event instead of click.
All in all:


const boxes = document.getElementsByName('ch');

boxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener("change", handle))
    
function handle(event) {
  const wasChecked = event.target.checked;
  for (box of boxes) {
    box.checked = false;
  }
  event.target.checked = wasChecked;
}
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 1">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 2">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 3">
<input type="checkbox" name="ch" id="Chapter 4">



Just use radios
Instead of the above, why not use radios? They're designed for your use case. You said that you "want the possibility to uncheck by clicking on the subject." You can add that to radios. Maybe not easier for you, but less confusing for your users.
This does mean you'll have to use the click event instead of the change or input events (as far as I can tell). But that is insignificant.
You will need to record the previous state to detect if the click is on an already selected radio. I have used data attributes for this, but you could use a variable and record the last selected value.


const boxes = document.getElementsByName('ch');

boxes.forEach(box => box.dataset.checked = false)
boxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener("click", handle))

function handle(event) {
  const wasChecked = event.target.dataset.checked == "true";
  for (box of boxes) {
    box.checked = false;
    box.dataset.checked = false;
  }
  event.target.checked = !wasChecked;
  event.target.dataset.checked = !wasChecked;
}
<input type="radio" name="ch" value="Chapter 1">
<input type="radio" name="ch" value="Chapter 2">
<input type="radio" name="ch" value="Chapter 3">
<input type="radio" name="ch" value="Chapter 4">




Quoting the OP ...

I am trying to implement a function which will uncheck other checkboxes when a new one is clicked. I am doing this instead of using radio because I want the possibility to uncheck by clicking on the subject.

From my above comment ...

@Ryochi ... If you want to be able to uncheck a radio-control from a radio-group you should implement it exactly that way. Why? Because with radio-controls and radio-groups you already  get all the expected/desired behavior for free except the unchecking of all of a radio-group's radio-controls; Second, implementing the behavior of a radio-group based on checkbox-controls is more complex than enabling the uncheck-behavior of a radio-group and third, a user expects a certain behavior from checkboxes; a radio-control like switching is the last what the user does expect.

The next provided example code implements a generic approach for unchecking any radio-group's last checked radio-control ...


function enableRadioGroupUncheckBehavior() {
  const lastRadioGroupValues = new WeakMap;

  function handleRadioGroupUncheck({ target }) {
    target = target.closest('[type="radio"]');

    if (target) {
      const nodeList = target.form.elements[target.name];

      if (
        lastRadioGroupValues.get(nodeList) !== nodeList.value
      ) {
        lastRadioGroupValues.set(nodeList, nodeList.value);
      } else {
        lastRadioGroupValues.delete(nodeList);

        target.checked = false;
      }
    }
  }
  document
    .querySelectorAll('form')
    .forEach(elm => {
      elm.addEventListener('click', handleRadioGroupUncheck)
    });
}

enableRadioGroupUncheckBehavior();
body { margin: 0; }
fieldset {
  margin: 0 0 8px 0;
  padding: 8px 4px 4px 4px;
}
[type="radio"] {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
  margin: 1.4em 0 0 0;
}
[type="radio"]:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.4em;
  left: .3em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: attr(value);
}
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Chapters of Podcast A (unchecking a chapter is enabled)</legend>

    <input type="radio" name="podcast-a-chapter" value="Chapter 1" />
    <input type="radio" name="podcast-a-chapter" value="Chapter 2" />
    <input type="radio" name="podcast-a-chapter" value="Chapter 3" />
    <input type="radio" name="podcast-a-chapter" value="Chapter 4" />
    <input type="radio" name="podcast-a-chapter" value="Chapter 5" />
    <input type="radio" name="podcast-a-chapter" value="Chapter 6" />
    <input type="radio" name="podcast-a-chapter" value="Chapter 7" />
    <input type="radio" name="podcast-a-chapter" value="Chapter 8" />
    <input type="radio" name="podcast-a-chapter" value="Chapter 9" />

  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Chapters of Book B (unchecking a chapter is enabled)</legend>

    <input type="radio" name="book-b-chapter" value="Chapter 1" />
    <input type="radio" name="book-b-chapter" value="Chapter 2" />
    <input type="radio" name="book-b-chapter" value="Chapter 3" />
    <input type="radio" name="book-b-chapter" value="Chapter 4" />
    <input type="radio" name="book-b-chapter" value="Chapter 5" />
    <input type="radio" name="book-b-chapter" value="Chapter 6" />
    <input type="radio" name="book-b-chapter" value="Chapter 7" />
    <input type="radio" name="book-b-chapter" value="Chapter 8" />
    <input type="radio" name="book-b-chapter" value="Chapter 9" />
    <input type="radio" name="book-b-chapter" value="Chapter 10" />
    <input type="radio" name="book-b-chapter" value="Chapter 11" />
    <input type="radio" name="book-b-chapter" value="Chapter 12" />
    <input type="radio" name="book-b-chapter" value="Chapter 13" />

  </fieldset>
</form>




In the code you provided, you are trying to check/uncheck all of the boxes except the one that is clicked but the break makes it only toggle one.
function uncheck(obj) {
  let ch = document.getElementsByName("ch");
  for (let i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    if (ch[i].id != obj.id) {
      ch[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
}

This way, it loops through the entire code setting each checkbox to false except for the one the user clicks on.

Please add a note that simply removing the break would have caused unchecking a box to check all the other boxes. This is an important issue in the original code.

The below function will give you a radio like behavior. But if you uncheck from checked status then what happened? In case of radio you can't uncheck.
function uncheck(obj) {
  var ch = document.getElementsByName('ch');

  if (!obj.checked) {
    // Implement if required
  }

  // This will give you radio like behaviour except obj uncheck case
  for (var i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    if (ch[i].id != obj.id && ch[i].checked) {
      ch[i].checked = !obj.checked;
      break;
    }
  }
}


If I understand your problem, then your code is perfectly alright.
JUST REMOVE BREAK FROM YOUR CODE!
Like:
if (ch[i].id != obj.id) {
  ch[i].checked = !obj.checked;
}


Nope, that reveals a bigger issue: it will check all the other boxes when one is unchecked.
